# Java : Can I keep information from event method through each call without using class static vars?

Tags: java, oop, events

In any event method (ie. method that is called on an event)
How would I keep information from the previous call in any other way than making a class static variable that keeps the old information ?

example:

```
Class X {
   static boolean ex = false;
   static int calledTimes;
   void OnClickEvent() {
    if(calledTimes<=5)
     {
    calledTimes++; 
     ex = true;
     }
    else
    ex = false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to keep the information other than this static flag ?
As in my case I have a lot of information that I keep for each call and I don't want too much class variables.

Any ideas ?

**More Info : The case I have calls a method while traversing each line in a text file.**
I need a general soln that is not only applied to gui events

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to avoid class variables?

Comment: I have a lot of information that I need to get from each call.
Till now I have about 6 variables to be used and this makes the class look horrible

Comment: You don't need to make `ex` and `calledTimes` static. Then you can maintain instance-specific values.

Comment: Where is this information being used?

Comment: used in the same function to make actions according to these flags in the next callback for this function

Comment: Yeah, then they don't need to be static then. And to be clear, we're talking about EventListeners, not "events", right?

Comment: yes, I tried private and it worked.
but I'm checking if I cannot define them to be seen by the whole class.
just inside the call method only but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using instance variables instead of class variables and manipulating them using an instance. This way the instance can keep the state in the form of instance variables.

If you want to keep this class definition clean, you can maintain another object as instance variable to retain state and access the individual variables using accessors.

Take a look at this example implementation:

```
public class X {

    private State state;

    // constructor to instantiate state

    void OnClickEvent() {
        if (state.getCalledTimes() <= 5) {
            state.incrementCalledTimes();
            state.setEx(true);
        } else
            state.setEx(false);
    }

}
```

And the `State` class which maintains object information:

```
public class State {

    private boolean ex;
    private int calledTimes;

    public void setEx(boolean ex) {
        this.ex = ex;
    }

    public int getCalledTimes() {
        return calledTimes;
    }

    public void incrementCalledTimes() {
        calledTimes++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an (Event)Listener class instance, that listens to certain calls (e.g. `onClickEvent()`), then even *instance properties* are enough, you don't need static properties.

The instance properties are also preserved, because the listener calls are made to the same object instance.

```
Class X {
private boolean ex = false;
private int calledTimes;

public void onClickEvent() {
    if(calledTimes<=5) {   
        calledTimes++; 
        ex = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No I don't, I ask if there's a general solution.
not only for certain events that have listeners

Comment: That's an antipattern. That ties class `A` to class `B`, directly. You cannot modify the behaviour in any way (interfacing, subclassing, wrapping, ...)

Comment: Yes, It worked for private but I need to separate this from the class.
I wished to define them in the method itself but I couldn't .
Is there any way not to define these vars to be only for the method and not tied to the class ?

Comment: I'm not really clear what the purpose is, but if you want to organize the information in a separate class, you can do it. You can have an instance reference to the info-holder object instance, that can be accessed from any method it is passed to.

Answer (score 0):

By separating your event listener out into a different class, you can specify fields in that class. For example, using the MouseListener Interface:

```
public class Listener implements MouseListener {

// Created a class that implements the MouseListener Interface.
// Because this is my own class I can specify some instance variables.

private boolean hasBeenClicked;

public Listener()
{
    this.hasBeenClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    if(hasBeenClicked)
    {
        System.out.println("I've already been clicked!");
                    // A Click has already occurred.
    }
    else
    {
        hasBeenClicked = true;
                    // A click has not occurred, so setting the value to true.
    }

}
```